# How to control Maxon Motor by using ROS_CANopen

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am a newbie to ROS, I would like to use ROS_CANopen package to connect with my robot, I want to set different modes of operation for position and current control.  After that, I would like to use MoveIt to control my robot. However, I checked from previous [ROSAnswer](http://answers.ros.org/question/233735/how-to-used-ros_canopen/) about ROS_CANopen can not find more detail tutorials on how use it.

Here is my hardware configuration:

1. A [USB-to-CAN compact](https://www.ixxat.com/products/products-industrial/pc-interfaces/pc-can-interfaces/details-pc-can-interfaces) made by IXXAT is used to communicate between my laptop and the robot. The Linux driver called IXXAT [socketcan driver](https://www.ixxat.com/products/products-industrial/pc-interfaces/pc-can-interfaces/socketcan).
2. The robot uses Maxon EPOS2 with CANopen. eds file is generated from EPOS studio.

OS: Ubunutu 14.04 with indigo installed.
I already tested with socketcan driver by using can-utils i.e. cansend can0 xxx.
Therefore, I can just use CANopen protocol-301 and 402 with command-line to control Maxon motor, in the meantime, use sockketcan_dump to verify command and status.

How to use Ros_CANopen? could someone give me a hint to do next steps or some examples I could refer to? or any package to run roslaunch to control ROS_CANopen?

Many thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250174/how-to-control-maxon-motor-by-using-ros_canopen/) by [CJ.Nilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/28645/cj.nilson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-12-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/44629/fan/) on 2019-08-16**:
Excuse me, I now have a USB-to-CAN device (kvaser leaf light v2), a motor! I want to know how to use ROS_CANopen and socketcan_driver to control motor rotation? Can you tell me what to do? This problem has been bothering me for a long time, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be more or less straightforward:

1. Setup SocketCAN (you already have this running): http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface#Initialize_NIC
2. Prepare URDF with sane limits (this is required for now, will be optional in the future): http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file
3. Prepare EDS/DCF, take special care for the PDO mapping (http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_402), use transmission type 1 (every sync)
4. Prepare driver config

- prepare chain config (http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node#Configuration)
- configure motor-specific settings, especially unit conversions (http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_motor_node)

5. Prepare controller config

- list of controllers (documentation varies, http://wiki.ros.org/ros_controllers)
- add a `required_drive_mode` to each motion controller, it takes the number of the mode to be used (http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_402#Drive_operation_modes)

6. Prepare a launchfile for canopen_motor_node

- upload driver config as private parameters
- upload controller config into namespace
- upload robot description

7. rosservice call [/namespace]/driver/init (http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node#Services)
8. start/switch the controllers (rqt_controller_manager, ontroller_manager, spawner etc.)

The EDS file parser is not really bullet proof (and EDS file format is rather flexibel) and might fail with some error indication.
In addition `ros_canopen` enforces strict typing, some EDS files list non-standard types for some objects (e.g. signed instead of unsigned). This must be fixed as well in the EDS.

A basic driver config looks like:

```
bus:
  device: can0
sync:
  interval_ms: 10  # 100Hz
  overflow: 0
defaults:
  eds_pkg: my_package
  eds_file: "config/MyDescription.dcf" # the parser reads EDS and DCF
nodes:
  my_joint:
    id: 1
```

controller config example: https://github.com/ipa320/canopen_test_utils/blob/indigo-devel/config/rig1_controller.yaml

Fairly complex examples: https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_robots/

It would be great if you could turn this into a tutorial on ROS Wiki based on your experiences :)

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CJ.Nilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/28645/cj.nilson/) on 2016-12-19**:
Thank you for the replies. I still have some questions regarding your replies.

- item 2:  I have created URDF to describe elements fo my robot, but why need URDF in ros_canopen
- item 5:  Why ros_canopen package need ros_control? Could you briefly introduce the main idea for using ros_control

**Comment by [CJ.Nilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/28645/cj.nilson/) on 2016-12-19**:
I'm trying to refer "schunk_robots and canopen_test_utils" as a model for item 4, 5 and 6.  Which packages do you recommend for my case? Thanks you very much.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-12-19**:
The URDF is used for getting the joint limits and to verify the names of the joints.

More information on ros_control can be found in the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control
And `schunk_robots` contains full-fledged examples..
If in doubt have a look at both.

**Comment by [CJ.Nilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/28645/cj.nilson/) on 2016-12-23**:
When I tried to do item 7 you listed, I met the [failure](http://answers.ros.org/question/250653/ros_canopen-with-schunk_lwa4d-initialization-fails/) during initializing the lwa4d,  have you ever meet this before ? Thanks for your reply

**Comment by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on 2018-06-01**:
Hello CJ and Mathias, please, could you help me with a similar problem in this question: [#q292882](https://answers.ros.org/question/292882/how-to-control-maxon-mcd-epos-with-ros_canopen-and-ixxat-adapter/)

Many thanks,
Jorge

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2018-12-06**:
@Mathias Lüdtke , When you say use transmission type 1, that is for both RxPDO and TxPDO ?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2018-12-10**:
Yes, for both. This is how we run it with Care-O-bot. It is not mandatory, but it enforces a deterministic data flow. Otherwise the timing would be arbitrary and might result in (small) jumps.

**Comment by [martinlucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/74707/martinlucan/) on 2021-07-06**:
hi @Mathias Lüdtke , following your steps to successfully control the motor, is user supposed to write and implement some additional hardware interface for Maxon motor, or it is yet included in ros_canopen packages?

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2021-07-06**:
It is possible to implement a dedicated motor implementation ([example](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_driver/blob/kinetic_dev/cob_elmo_homing/src/plugin.cpp)), but it should not be necessary in general. However, I have never tested the default implementation with Maxon motors.